# Hide link on discord bot message

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, youtube, discord, bots

Basically, i'm trying to send a YT video on discord through js bot, but without the link appearing. Can someone help me?

```
return message.channel.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d6wB4KyuUk&list=PLJxFlYsd38rLghWxPrtoX2mL7jXCrZq_M&index=12");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, unless you download the video as mp4 and upload it as a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EMBED:

```
const embed = {
    "video": {
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d6wB4KyuUk&list=PLJxFlYsd38rLghWxPrtoX2mL7jXCrZq_M&index=12"
    }
};
bot.sendMessage({
    to: channelID,
    message: embed
});
```